# Why does 'update()' not redirect to 'sox' using @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

At the moment I just want to test redirecting from the update method back to the sox method. But instead I get an error complaining about a missing `"update.jsp"`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sox/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ModelAttribute("formWrapper")
public final String update(HttpServletRequest request, 
 @ModelAttribute("formWrapper") FormWrapper formWrapper,
    BindingResult bindResult,
    ModelMap model)
{
    return "redirect:/sox";
}

@ModelAttribute("formWrapper")
FormWrapper setupForm()
{
    FormWrapper formWrapper = new FormWrapper();
    return formWrapper;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/sox", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String sox(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model)
{
    return "sox";
}
```

Comment: Show us your `web.xml` and Spring config files.

Comment: Sure. I just added web.xml, dispatcher-servlet and application-context. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the @ModelAttribute on the update method. Try it this way :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sox/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public final String update(HttpServletRequest request, 
     @ModelAttribute("formWrapper") FormWrapper formWrapper,
        BindingResult bindResult,
        ModelMap model)
    {
        return "redirect:/sox";
    }
```

When you add the @ModelAttribute to a method spring treats the return as a model attribute :

> Any other return type is considered to
>   be a single model attribute to be
>   exposed to the view, using the
>   attribute name specified through
>   @ModelAttribute at the method level
>   (or the default attribute name based
>   on the return type class name). The
>   model is implicitly enriched with
>   command objects and the results of
>   @ModelAttribute annotated reference
>   data accessor methods.

Look at 15.3.2.8 of the Spring Docs for more info: (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib)